# Efficient off-screen window buffer access in compositing window manager?

Tags: opengl, x11, glx

I'm writing a compositing window manager, and I've successfully redirected rendering of the top level window and its children using the Composite extension to X11.

I want to reparent one window to the overlay, map it, and create OpenGL textures from any other windows to be displayed in the first window.

It was my understanding that the functions defined in the `GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap` extension bind a texture to the contents of a pixmap, but in my application, I have to call it continuously to update the texture.

I used [this page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux:_Using_texture_from_pixmap_extension). as a reference, and my code is pretty similar.

Right now, my code creates a GLXPixmap from the window ID, binds the texture, then calls `glXBindTexImageEXT` with the window pixmap. I suspect the contents of the window are copied when I do this, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

EDIT: It's worth noting that I'm getting a lot of X errors upon creating the GLXPixmap from the X window ID. The error is `BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter)`, yet, strangely, it seems to work. Regardless, this seems to indicate that users are not supposed to create GLXPixmaps directly from a window ID. However, it seems there's no other clear way of obtaining a reference to the redirected window's pixmap.

EDIT: [This blog post](https://wingolog.org/archives/2008/07/26/so-you-want-to-build-a-compositor) offers some insight into the problem, though being from 2008, I question how much of it remains relevant.

Specifically, the section about kernel memory management:

> if I want to bind a GL texture to a pixmap corresponding to some other application, and I am not going to go through the X server to do so, then obviously the kernel itself has to know about X drawables. If I have a named pixmap open from one process that was created from another process, there needs to be a unified memory manager in the kernel
>
> ...
>
> You can't do direct TFP with free drivers, is the conclusion of that digression

Comment: Keith Packard has done a lot of work on compositing window managers for Linux that use modern GPU hardware, particularly for the open source Intel drivers. I've been to a LinuxConf Aus talk and he knows his stuff. Googling "keith packard window manager" turns up a lot of hits